# jquery select div class inside a form and add value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in my modal and I can select like :

```
$(".my-modal").click(function () {
        var app_modal = $(this).next('.modal').modal({backdrop: 'static'})
        var frm = app_modal.next('.myform')
        console.log(frm)
        frm.on('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            frm.class('.result').html('<div>Hellooww</div>');
        });
```

and my form is:

```
<form class="myform">
<div class="results"></div>
some form element
</form>
```

Here I want to put some `html` on class `.results` but I am unable to do this.. The form is in `form loop in django template`

How can I do this ??

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has no `.class()` function. Instead you can use `.find()` if the result element is a descendent of the form:

```
frm.find('.result').html('<div>Hellooww</div>');
```

If the result element is a sibling of the form then you can go up to the parent and find it like so

```
frm.parent().find('.result').html('<div>Hellooww</div>');
```

Comment: It didnt worked for me.. Can you please see my updates

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
frm.children(".results").html('<div>Hellooww</div>');
```